# How to read a char that has ASCII value in range 128-130 and convert it to int value

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, ascii, extended-ascii

I have an array of chars, some of them are ASCII 128 and 130 in decimal. I am trying to read them as normal chars, but instead of 128 I get 8218 as an int (casted to byte, got 26). I need to get that number between 128 and 130. I found some articles on Encodings, some people say I need to use Encoding 439.

Any ideas?

Comment: In C# char is 16bit. How do you read that array?

Comment: ASCII value of >=128 is going to be tricky in a 7-bit encoding. (i.e. there's no ASCII value 128) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII  Perhaps you should be using ISO-8859? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 , the most common 8 bit encoding.

Comment: Are you sure you want a char and not a byte? A c# char is 2 bytes... Can you show some code?

Answer (score 2):

A char (System.Char) in the CLR environment is an unsigned 16-bit number, a UTF-16 [code unit](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit). From the [Unicode Standard, Chapter 3, §3.9](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch03.pdf):

> *Code unit:* The minimal bit combination that can represent a
>   unit of encoded text for processing or interchange.
>
> - Code units are particular units of computer storage. Other character encoding
>     standards typically use code units defined as 8-bit units—that is, octets. The
>     Unicode Standard uses 8-bit code units in the UTF-8 encoding form, 16-bit code
>     units in the UTF-16 encoding form, and 32-bit code units in the UTF-32 encoding form.
> - A code unit is also referred to as a code value in the information industry.
> - In the Unicode Standard, specific values of some code units cannot be used to
>     represent an encoded character in isolation. This restriction applies to isolated
>     surrogate code units in UTF-16 and to the bytes 80–FF in UTF-8. Similar
>     restrictions apply for the implementations of other character encoding standards;
>     for example, the bytes 81–9F, E0–FC in SJIS (Shift-JIS) cannot represent an encoded
>     character by themselves.

Your "ASCII" text is no longer ASCII once it's in the CLR world. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and the code points 0x00–0x7F are maintained across all Unicode encodings (UTF-8, -16, -24, -32) for the sake of compatability. In the non-Unicode world, 0x80–0xFF have always had multiple character mappings (and don't even look at EBCDIC *vs* ASCII). Some ASCII implementations provided for parity as well: the high order bit would be set to maintain the desired parity.

- **Even parity.** The high order bit is set to maintain an even number of 'on' bits in the octet.
- **Odd parity.** The high order bit is set to maintain an odd number of 'on' bits in the octet.
- **No parity.** The high order bit is never set.

Presumably you're reading your "ASCII" text using a UTF-8 encoder/decoder (the CLR default). To get the numeric values you expect in your chars, you'll need to read the text using an encode/decoder suitable for the encoding your text is actually in (Windows 1252? something else?).

A better approach for you, perhaps, would be to read your text octet by octet as binary, using `System.IO.FileStream`, rather than `System.IO.TextReader` and its minions. Then you've got the raw octets and you can convert them to text as you wish, or do math on the raw octet values.